# Calculating average spend per month on aggregate or individual level - is there a difference?

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm looking at some spend data that resulted from a survey where respondents were asked how often one goes shopping in **one year** and how much they would spend on **one shopping trip**. Now the average spend per month is calculated by multiplying the total average frequency by total average spend thus average is on aggregate level. Would this calculation provide similar or different result if average spend per month is first calculated on individual level to then calculate the total average spend across the sample?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try it yourself:

- Person A goes shopping $25$ times a month ($300$ times a year) and spends $\$2$ each time.
- Person B goes shopping $1$ time a month ($12$ times a year) and spends $\$2000$ each time.

Comment: I forgot to mention that shopping frequency varies by person as the answers were selected from a nominal scale and spend was for one trip only. So to come to average spend per month what would be the best approach according to you? I suggest to calculate average spend per month based on scale mid-point of frequency and scale midpoint of spend and multiply to get average spend per month for each individual and then total all averages of individual spend per month and divide by total individuals. The other way would as you point out not consider outliers appropriately right?

Comment: My first inclination would be to do the multiplication at the individual level before averaging across the population.